# How do i send such POST request on android?

Tags: android, http, post

I have this format page

```
<html><head><script>
function sendForm(form)
{
      form.value.value = "{ \"y\": " + form.example2.value + " }"
      form.submit();
}
</script></head>
<body>
<form action="https://....WEBSITE..." method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="value">
number:<input type="text" name="example2">
<input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="sendForm(this.form);">
</form>
  </body>
</html>
```

and i wonder, how can i convert it to a post object in android?
i wish to send the exact same data from my android phone
assuming that i have a variable with my integer i wish to send and string representing my url.

Comment: tried something, have you ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `StringEntity` class. You can set the StringEntity object to your `HttpPost` using `setEntity()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("value", value));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("example2", example2_value));

try {
    HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 10000);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 10000);
    HttpClient httpClientpost = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://....WEBSITE...");

    UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8);
    post.setEntity(ent);


    HttpResponse responsePOST = httpClientpost.execute(post);
    HttpEntity resEntity = responsePOST.getEntity();
    String getresponse = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity); //Response from the server
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I changed it a little, with only 1 "params.add" with "value", msg, where msg is a var i have. when it reaches the line `HttpResponse responsePOST = httpClientpost.execute(post)` it crashes. any reason why?